# Rounding a matrix of numbers with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a matrix of numbers in Excel consisting of numerical data.  I want Excel to display each cell rounded to 5 significant figures.

How would I go about this?  Is it possible to perform the rounding on all cells at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your matrix is in A1:D10 then you can create a "rounded matrix" adjacent to that, e.g. in G1 use this formula

`=ROUND(A1,4-INT(LOG(A1,10)))`

copy down and across to J10 to get your new data rounded to 5 significant figures in `G1:J10`

Answer (score 0):

`Round()` etc. work in array formulas, so with `ctrl-shift-return` you can enter
`{=round(A1:D10,4-int(log10(A1:D10)))}` in another 4x10 cell range to do it on all cells at once.